# Wordpress API returns 403 for PUT only

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I have a wordpress website (actually it's my customer's site), which installed WooCommerce plugin. When I send POST/GET requests to get/create woocommerce products, it works as expected. But when I send PUT requests, wordpress always returns this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>403 Forbidden</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H1>Forbidden</H1>
You don't have permission to access /wp-json/wc/v2/products/6030 on this server.
        <HR>
        <I>nameofthewebsite.com</I>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

So what can I do to fix this?

// It's a very simple PUT request:

```
Endpoint: https://nameofthewebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/6030
Headers: Content-Type:application/json, <Basic Auth header>
Body: { "weight":"1" }
```

The same auth header works for POST/GET so I think it's not authenticate problem.

Comment: Can you show how you are making your PUT request

Comment: @Und3rTow please see my updated question

Comment: What are you using to send the request? curl, php, node, etc? I ask because depending what you are using, the payload may need to be an array, not an object, for example with PHP, the payload should be an array, as per the [docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#update-a-product).  Otherwise it may be possible that your server does not accept the PUT method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at yout .htaccess file.
If it looks like this:

```
<Limit GET POST>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Limit>
```

GET and POST commands are allowed, PUT and DELETE not.
Solution: delete the lines 
(worked for me)